# Difference between spring batch remote chunking and remote partitioning

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

What is the difference between spring batch remote chunking and remote partitioning?

I can not understand the difference between remote chunking and remote partitioning in spring batch. Could anybody please explain?

Comment: Yeah, Thanks. I will make sure i do it hereafter.

Comment: http://www.ontheserverside.com/blog/2014/07/23/horizontal-and-vertical-scaling-strategies-for-batch-applications/

Answer (score 45, accepted):

**Remote Partitioning**

Partitioning is a master/worker step configuration that allows for partitions of data to be processed in parallel.  Each partition is described via some metadata.  For example, if you were processing a database table, partition 1 may be ids 0-100, partition 2 being 101-200, etc.  For Spring Batch, a master step uses a [Partitioner](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/index.html?org/springframework/batch/core/partition/support/Partitioner.html) to generate ExecutionContexts that contain the metadata for each partition.  These ExecutionContexts are distributed to worker steps for processing by a [PartitionHandler](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/index.html?org/springframework/batch/core/partition/support/Partitioner.html) (for remote partitioning, the [MessageChannelPartitionHandler](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch-admin/trunk/spring-batch-integration/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/integration/partition/MessageChannelPartitionHandler.html) is typically used).  The workers execute their step and return the resulting statuses for aggregation by the master.

Things to note about remote partitioning:

- Input and output are local to the workers.  For example, if the input is a file, the workers need access to the file.
- Workers need access to the JobRepository.  Workers are fully defined Spring Batch steps and so they need JobRepository access.

**Remote Chunking**

Remote chunking is similar to remote partitioning in that it is a master/worker configuration.  However with remote chunking, the data is read at by the master and sent over the wire to the worker for processing.  Once the processing is done, the result of the ItemProcessor is returned to the master for writing.

Things to note about remote chunking:

- All I/O is done by the master.
- The workers handle processing only and therefore do not need JobRepository access.
- Remote chunking is more I/O intensive than remote partitioning since the actual data is sent over the wire instead of metadata describing it.

I did a talk on scaling Spring Batch and do a demonstration of remote partitioning that you can watch here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CYTj5YT7CZU

*Community Edit: In current documentation the term slave was replaced by worker, the answer has been edited to reflect that. Note some comments still reference the old term.*

Comment: Thanks Michael Minella

Comment: can we use REST calls for communication between master and slave instead of JMS?

Comment: For remote partitioning, yes you can use REST calls to communicate.

Comment: @Michael Minella could you provide example of REST communication between master and slave for remote partitioning?

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/master/spring-batch-samples#partitioning-sample here slave doesn't write any data back to the master

Comment: Why can't the slave do I/O?  i.e. master sends a batch of data to a slave, the slave does some processing and then inserts the result into a db.

Comment: @MichaelMinella When using RemotePartitioning, do the workers (slaves, as mentioned above) run in their own process and own JVM?

Comment: With remote partitioning, yes. You can do partitioning without it being remote as well. Then the partitions run in threads within the same JVM.

Answer (score 0):

**Remote Chunking**

Remote chunking is a manager/worker approach which allows Spring Batch developers to scale batch applications.

In remote chunking, the Step processing is split across multiple processes, communicating with each other through some messaging middleware.

Processing and writing are done by the worker, while reading is done by the master. The manager has to read and then pass actual records to the worker via the wire (eg: kafka topic).

[Practical example](https://medium.com/@eddybayonne1/remote-chunking-with-spring-batch-integration-63c9df75e361)

Tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-MFtwajUalg

**Remote Partitioning**

Remote partitioning allows you to fan out the work load to multiple JVMs. Out of the box , Spring Batch provides message-based PartitionHandler that can be used to fan out processing across JVMs.

Pro: Restartability. Spans across JVMs. Thread safety

Con: Complex set up of the paritioner and worker deployment